# Parsing Comparison and Version Numbers on Strings

Tags: php, laravel, parsing

I have version strings e.g. `>=1.0.0.1` The string can also be `<2.0`, or `<0.1-alpha`. How can I parse the string to be separated values such as `">="` - `"1.0.0.1"` or `"<"` -`"0.1-alpha`"` consistently?

Here is what I have so far and it works but I find it extremely ugly/messy. any tips to clean it up would be greatly appreciated.

I'm using Laravel (string helpers are welcome). this must also work for other versions of the string examples. It always follows `comparison` then `version`:

`>=1.0.0`
`<3.0`
`>0.01-alpha` ... etc

```
public function test_version_compare()
{
    $version = ">=4.0.0";

    $resolved_comparison = null;
    $resolved_version = null;

    $version_array = str_split($version);

    foreach ($version_array as $key => $array) {
        if (is_numeric($array)) {
            $version_pos = $key;

            break;
        }
    }

    foreach ($version_array as $key => $array) {
        if ($version_pos > $key) {
            $resolved_comparison = $resolved_comparison.$array;
        } else {
            $resolved_version = $resolved_version.$array;
        }
    }

    $this->assertEquals('>=', $resolved_comparison);
    $this->assertEquals('4.0.0', $resolved_version);

}
```

Comment: hi there ahnikle - did you come along with the cleanup or a solution? it would be great to get to know. Have a great day!

Comment: Hey @zero - no, unfortunately, i've been using that mess of my original solution. lol hoping for one soon!